# Argument 1 passed to x must be an instance of y, string given,

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I try to execute a post request, but it shows me this error Argument 1 passed to x::addPhoto() must be an instance of y, string given, this argument in my case is the current authenticated user, i use this code to have it:

```
    $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

but this code does not give a user instance as result , it gives me a string, 
how to solve that please ?

Comment: what string is giving to you?

Comment: in error, it shows me that the argument is a string ,

Comment: can you edit your question with the full error text?

Comment: If you are not logged in, then getUser() returns the string "anon."
Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: What Symfony version are you running?
Since some version (don't know which one) you can just use $this->getUser() from inside a controller. Maybe try that.

Comment: i'm using symfony 2.8

Comment: when i try to user $this->getUser(), it gives me this error Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to x::addPhoto() must be an instance of Y, null given

Comment: get user give as result an instance of each class ??

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in? Everything so far hints towards not being logged in. What does the dev toolbar display?

Comment: I am logged in, otherwise the page will not be displayed, because I can not access without using the access token ..

Comment: You are authenticated anonymously, so not authenticated, you can look at the debug bar, you should see Anonymous in the security part.

Comment: No it is logged in as the name of the user

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had a problem of class mapping,

```
     $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

this code works in symfony 2.8, thank you for your responses

Comment: So what specifically did you do to fix your problem?

Comment: the user class was defined in other bundle , and it was a problem of defining the path of the inversed entity, that's all